# Multiple Enlightning

Tags: support, badges, serial-voting

I have had the honour to be awarded three(!) *Enlightened* badges within a single(!) minute today. Not that I want to complain, but since the three questions were from different askers and of different age, I am somewhat curious if this happened by pure chance ... ? Maybe even a bug?

Comment: This sounds as if someone just went through some random sampling of your 9-vote answers and upvoted them... You may want to wait 24 hours and see if the voting is undone by the "serial upvoting" script.

Comment: But they say enlightning never strikes twice....

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thrice ain't twice ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations. You've been a "victim" of a serial upvoter.

Sometimes people target "near-badge" posts, and sometimes they just go through everything and upvote.

In a few hours (about five, which is 2:00 UTC) the script which detects these sort of things should reverse these votes. But the badges will stay.

(As change would have it, I had both these kind of serial upvotes happening to me today.)

Comment: I guess someone wanted to push you over 100K... maybe had a congratulatory meta post prepared, and just could not wait... (If so, you could become the only user to reach 100K *twice*).

Comment: @40votes: I guess so.

Comment: Well, at least in the case of upvoting me, 100k can hardly have been the objective :)

Comment: @Hagen: Maybe it's someone with a very long term goal! ;-)

Comment: I consider this case closed - though even at this moment (more than 24 hours later) the same three answers still have their 10 upvotes. Ah, and I missed your 100K traversal - congrats. You could still repeat the experience by setting a bounty ;)